# Loop through certain integers and in the order that I specify

Tags: matlab

The normal loop is

```
for i=1:50

end
```

but I want to execute the loop through certain integers and in the order that I specify

```
for i=4,3,45,34,23,31

end
```

How can I do that in Matlab?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's easy:

```
for i = [4,3,45,34,23,31]
```

The argument to `for` in Matlab is a matrix. 1:50 creates a matrix (vector) of numbers 1..50. It is just a special case of Matlab `for`-usage.

Comment: It should be emphasized that _i_ must be a row vector (as it is in @ypnos's solution) to work as the OP expects. If _i_ is a column vector there will only be one iteration as the [FOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/for.html) construct employs column-based indexing into the iterator array.